# Is Dexterity proficiency modifier added to AC?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, armor-class

I'm playing as a bard that has a proficiency bonus that's added to Dexterity. When calculating the character's Armor Class, do I add *only* the base Dexterity modifier or do I add the base Dexterity modifier and the proficiency modifier?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [Does Jack of all trades affect AC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106458/does-jack-of-all-trades-affect-ac), if that's where you believe the proficiency bonus to be coming from.

Comment: relevant meta: [how do we handle it when the asker's confused](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/how-do-we-handle-it-when-the-askers-problem-is-just-that-theyre-confused)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. It's possible this question is a duplicate of another question. If it isn't, please make it clear in the question that this is not the case by differentiating it from the possible duplicate. If it is, the question will be put on hold shortly—that's not a punishment and you've done nothing wrong by asking it. Also, I edited this question a little; make sure it's still asking what you need answered. No matter what, though, thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: I don't understand why people think this is a duplicate: there's nothing in the post to indicate OP's thinking about JoaT. (That would apply to everything, not just dex.)

Comment: @nitsua60 I wasn't interpreting the question as 'I have a proficiency bonus that applies to *only* dex', but rather only dex was being mentioned because it's the only stat relevant to his question about AC. And I'm assuming JoaT because it's the only thing I know of that could cause the confusion of applying proficiency to a raw ability.

Comment: If I'm right that you've got some fundamental questions about how things work, [chat] might be a good resource to talk through some of these issues once you've got 20 rep. There are almost always friendly 5e experts in there who are happy to help!

Comment: Is your table using the "Ability Check Proficiencies by Class" variant from page 263 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Jack of all trades affect AC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106458/does-jack-of-all-trades-affect-ac)

Answer (score 12):

> "a proficiency bonus that's added to dex."

That's not a thing. Your proficiency bonus might be added to some dexterity checks if you're proficient in a dex-based skill, and it is to your dexterity saves. But there's nothing like what you describe, where proficiency's just added to everything that references dexterity. (Even Jack of All Trades only applies to ability checks.)

Now, to calculating AC: the armor you're wearing or the spell you're using or the race or class feature implicated will tell you how to calculate your AC. If you would have multiple ways of calculating AC they function independently, and you choose one. Assuming you're wearing armor you might add some or all or none of your dexterity modifier as part of the AC calculation. Nothing I know of would bring your proficiency bonus to the AC-calculation table.

Comment: The only way I know of to add the proficiency bonus to AC is the Defensive Duelist Feat. And that is only against a single melee attack, and takes your Reaction.